# Why Docker daemon can not access localhost address?

Tags: docker, containers, daemon

Currently I'm experiencing with the Docker Engine API and trying to build a simple image.
I have Windows 10 with WSL2, I can call the API via the unix socket (`/var/run/docker.sock`) or via the exposed daemon on TCP port 2375.

The endpoint that I'm calling is the [/build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ImageBuild) endpoint. I'm using the `remote` query parameter, so the daemon will try to fetch the content of this remote address and use it for building the image. I have also created a tiny NodeJS server that serves a text file (the Dockerfile), and its onyl endpoint will be the remote address for my Docker build.

First, I was starting the Node server on my host machine with a simple npm start command. Then I provided the local endpoint address (something like `http://localhost:4000/Dockerfile`) for the /build endpoint, but it failed with a reason:

```
{
    "message": "error downloading remote context http://localhost:4000/Dockerfile: Get http://localhost:4000/Dockerfile: dial tcp localhost:4000: connect: connection refused"
}
```

Then I also tried the same with a Dockerized version of the Node server (simply built an image from my code and exposed it to the same host port). This time it worked perfectly, with the exact same remote parameter: `http://localhost:4000/Dockerfile`.

At this point, I'm fine with my solution, as I wanted to run the Node server inside a container anyways. But, I would also like to understand what happened and why it happened? I can see, that it was because of some kind of networking. I assume that after putting my Node server inside a container, it became part of a network (I think it should be Docker's default `bridge` network) and after that my Docker daemon could access it, but I'm not sure as I couldn't find any information about it on the internet. Or maybe the Docker daemon is running in a specific network, which can not access addresses on the host machine?

**Update #1**

I made a minimal progress in the investigation. I still don't know why the `localhost` address was working when I switched to Dockerized version of the Node server, but I found 2 alternatives for the remote address.

The key was, that I found out that when I'm starting my Node server with `npm start`, I can access it with two different IP addresses, depending on in which terminal I have executed the command. I have regular Windows terminal with Node installed on my Windows, and I also have WSL terminal with its own installed Node.

If I run the `ipconfig`/`ifconfig` commands inside these terminals, I also get different Ethernet addresses, something like: `192.168.1.110` for Windows and `192.168.106.100` for WSL. When I used these IP addresses (depending on where I started my Node server), my Docker daemon could reach the endpoint. But the localhost solution still not works if I not start it from Docker.

Answer (score 1):

On your local machine, `localhost` points to your local machine (sic!). But if you run an application in a Docker container, the address `localhost` points to the container environment.

But there's a simple solution for that: Just use `host.docker.internal`. Docker maps this address to your local machine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but sadly it not answers my question. Let me rephrase it a little bit. I used the same remote address (`http://localhost:4000/Dockerfile`) when I was calling the /build endpoint of the Docker Engine API.
The remote address is served by my small Node app.
First time, I ran this app with npm start on my host machine, but seems like the daemon couldn't access this address.
Second time, I ran my app inside a Docker container and the daemon could access it without any problem (I was using the same remote address).
What is the difference? Why the second solution works?

Answer (score 0):

Similar things happened to me today, I was trying to docker pull from a localhost container registry which failed, but I was able to whitelist and pull from host.docker.internal tho, maybe the container tool uses the docker network interface as well.

Hope this helps somebody.